# magento https links

Tags: magento, https

Magento has in built functionality to use https for my account pages , login page and checkout pages. However, we're finding that only the images and script links are dynamically changing to https. All the page links are not changing in these secure area and have http links instead. We are using Magento 1.7

We're looking for a possible answer or some actual help here and are willing to pay for it.

Any suggestions?

Comment: It seems that you use some cms or static blocks on secure pages. So links (src to images) are setted in not preferable way. You should find that blocks and change that urls to right ones

Comment: No, images and scripts are changing correctly to https. Its the page links (like footer, header, and navigation links that are not changing. Admin settings are correct for https settings. You can view our check out here: http://alaskachoicecuts.com

Comment: There is one request through HTTP:
`http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/AKChoiceCuts.json?callback=jQuery17105989684020169079_1344030241894&_=1344030242120`. Found using firebug

Comment: Thank you Serjio. Much appreciated. Why is it that when I view the source code, I see http links in the top nav and lower footer area? Is that just smart coding, or is it an error?

Comment: Links may be has both https and http prefixes in their `href` attribute it's not necessary. But all resources should be loaded through https (images, scripts, stylesheets, etc.). All of them is loaded, except one that was described above.